# Swipe between UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

Say I have 2 UIButtons next to each other and both of them will turn from white to black when I put my finger on them.

That obviously works fine, but if I put my finger on button 1 it turns black and then when I move my finger over the button 2 without lifting my finger, button 2 doesn't turn black, button 1 is still black.

So how can I "swipe" over one button and then over another one and change the highlighted button from the first one to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

In your viewcontroller override the touchesMoved event. This will tell you when touches occur. The problem is that your buttons will have to have userInteractionEnabled set to NO so that they don't gobble the touch event. This will be ok if you're trying to do a custom slider or something where you don't need the actual button events.

Then in the touchesMoved you can loop through your buttons and see which button is pressed. Here is some code stolen from an excellent answer at [Highlight the button when drag enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938445/highlight-the-button-when-drag-enter)

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
for (UITouch *t in touches) {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [t locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint testPoint = [self.view convertPoint:touchPoint toView:aButton];
    if ([aButton pointInside:testPoint withEvent:event]) {
        //Do something
    }
    //rest of code
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.button1 addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(dragEnter:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
[self.button2 addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(dragEnter:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];

[self.button1 addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(dragExit:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
[self.button2 addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(dragExit:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];

- (void)dragEnter:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.highlighted = YES;
}

- (void)dragExit:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.highlighted = NO;
}
```

Comment: `dragExit` is called when my finger leaves the first button but `dragEnter` is never called.

Comment: Try UIControlEventTouchDragInside